# What is Jacobian about the "Jacobian Edge" in $E_\mathrm{T}$ distributions?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology

Particle physicists often talk of a ["Jacobian Edge"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=&as_epq=jacobian+edge) in distributions, i.e. when looking at the $E_\mathrm{T}$ distribution of $W \to e \nu$ decays at rest. How is this related to the Jacobian determinant we all know about?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have a $W^+$ decaying (at rest) in the electron channel, so $W^+\rightarrow e^+ \nu$ . The transverse momentum of the electron is given by (neglecting electron mass, which is very small compared to $M_W$):
$$p_t=\frac{M_W}{2}*\sin{\theta}$$
Now you want to have the differential cross section versus $p_t$ so $\frac{d\sigma}{d p_t}$. Following derivative rules and using the previuos expression of $p_t$ you get:
$$\frac{d\sigma}{d p_t}=\frac{d\sigma}{d \cos{\theta}}*\frac{d\cos{\theta}}{dp_t}=\frac{d\sigma}{d cos{\theta}}*\frac{2p_t}{M_W}*\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{M_W}{2})^2-p_t^2}}$$
From this formula you can see that you have a maximum of the cross section at $p_t=\frac{M_W}{2}$ and then a fast drop off, so an "edge". The term "Jacobian"  for this edge comes from the fact that this peak comes from the transformation of variables described here.